# Relational database parent-child with parent partially dependent on child for information to be complete

Tags: sql, database, relational

| form_id | date_submitted |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/08/22 |

| completer_id | name | signature | form_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 38ehdsdj | 1 |

I have a digital form that is submitted and stored in my SQL database. There are two tables that are relevant to my question. The 'forms' table, which includes form_id and date_submitted (forget any form input data exists for this question). I also want to store the unique employee email of the person who submitted the form, and also the signature that they made on the form. If it was just their email, I'd just have another column within the forms table. However, the signature has to be collected for each form submission by that person (the whole point of a signature, to verify it). Since signature belongs to the person, I've created a second table called form_completers, with four columns: completer_id, name, signature, and form_id (foreign key to forms table). Since the form_completers table references the forms table, form_completers is the child. From my understanding, parents should be able to exist and make sense independent of children. If a forms_completer entry was to be removed, the data for the form would be incomplete, so in a way the parent (forms) is dependent on the child (forms_completer) in order for the form data to be complete. Am I thinking about this in the right way?

Comment: form_completers is the parent. One form completers record has many forms records right? You can use any terminology you like but if you have a forms record that references a form_completers record, you cannot delete that form_competers record (use a foreign key constraint to enforce this)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actually my intention was one-to-one. Since the signature must be captured each time that person fills out a form, there can only be one form_completers row for each one form. The only other way I see doing this is to split signatures into another table, so one person can complete many forms, but there is also a unique signature attached to that particular form submission.

Comment: If the signature is truly unique on each form (i.e. a binary representation of a picture of a signature on a form), then there is no point putting it in another table. It goes into the form table.

Comment: You can keep your form_completers table as a list of all possible people that could complete a form. Then you would put another `form_completer` column in `form` as a foreign key, and remove `form_id` (as well as `signature`) from `form_completer`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `form_id` column from `completers`.

Add a `completers_id` column to `forms`.

A person can complete many forms, but a form has exactly 1 completer.

Comment: Thanks, but this would mean that the same signature is used for multiple forms, which defeats the point of signing each form. I think the best option is to do what you said, but then have a signatures table that captures all unique signatures, and then have a FK on the completers table that references the unique signature?

Comment: @TWilliamson can a signature be used for more than one form?

Comment: no, the signature should be unique to a form because it's used to verify that the right person did in fact complete that form. However I didn't think it belonged in the form table because that would make it independent (in terms of direct relationships) of whoever completed the form. That's why I was trying to directly associate it with a form completer

Comment: Put the signature column in the forms table.